# tailwindcss different output css files for every pages

Tags: html, css, laravel, user-interface, tailwind-css

i have a project with Laravel using Tailwindss for ui developement.
how to get different css files in output from tailwindss, how to configure tailwind to do that for me?!

like below diagram :

"resources/view/admin/*" =>>> public/css/admin.css ( 30KB )

"resources/view/writers/*" =>>> public/css/writers.css ( 20KB )
....

actualy i want to have less unusabele css in output files and the output css file sizes can be smaller.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can have different folder configeration for tailwindcss, to sole  this problem and this worked for me.

like :

[image]